# Dynamic change of min-width

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple piece of code, resulting in blue span element overflowing out of yellow and black box.

I know, I can use `overflow` property to hide/scroll it, but I rather need to resize the `#inner` and `#outer` containers to cover it (so that scrollbar would rather be on whole page instead of in the containing `div`). Is there any way?

The content ( = width) of "blue span" is dynamicly generated from application?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    #outer {background: black; width: 300px; margin: 10px auto; padding: 20px; }
    #inner {background: yellow; min-width: 200px; height: 200px; }
    #inner span { background: blue; display: block; width: 400px; }
</style>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Does your #inner span element need an width of 400px? You could remove the width and make the #inner span display: block. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y49U7/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two outer boxes to resize dynamically based on the content thats inserted in the span, you will have to reconsider your approach. All boxes that scale dynamically cannot have a width defined, so they cannot be centred using the margin: auto. However, it is possible to achieve the same effect by wrapping the whole thing into another box that covers the full width of the page, text-align centring that box and then making the outer box displayed inline-block. This is the code that works. Now you can add a min-width to the content box if you want and it will scale nicely. Heres some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<style type="text/css"> 
    #wrap {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #outer {
        display: inline-block;
        background: black;  
        margin: 10px 0; 
        padding: 20px; 
    }
    #inner {
        background: yellow;  
        height: 200px; 
    }
    #inner span { 
        background: blue; 
        display: block;  
    }
</style>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <span>&nbsp;</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so you can add % units for your divisions to make it as perfect

Here is the CSS

```
#outer {background: black; width: 300px; margin: 10px auto; padding: 20px; } 
#inner {background: yellow; min-width: 200px; height: 200px; }
#inner span { background: blue; display: block; }
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedmusthafac/n6CEx/

I think so this is what you are expecting for??